# Is it possible to reset password of Switch CISCO 3500?

Tags: cisco, switch, telnet

With telnet, is it possible to reset password of a CISCO's switch or you have to connect to the console port?

Thanks for response..

Comment: I sure hope not ... that would be terribly insecure.

Comment: +1 for it being horribly insecure !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only method I've ever used is reseting the switch and following the procedure below via console. I don't believe there has ever been a way to do it via telnet. On the other hand snmp security has been quite bad in the past... if you have rw snmp strings that might be an option.

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps628/products_password_recovery09186a0080094184.shtml